# Outdoor Bluetooth scanner

Tags: bluetooth, windows

I need a computer that comes with a Bluetooth antenna, GPIO pins (only need one 5v output to trigger a door), ethernet port, and can execute .NET code that I have developed.

I'm currently experimenting with a raspberry PI 3 but I'm afraid it wont be able to handle the desert heat. It regularly hits 120F during the summer, inside a metal housing can reach up to 150F on a hot day. It also rains but I figured a good housing could prevent issues with that.

Any suggestions?